# How to println text in wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have some text which I want to have on separate lines.

I try to `println` this with label:

```
add(new Label("output",output));

<span wicket:id="output">Will be replaced</span>
```

Problem with this code it that  it is ignoring formatting new line. Is there better way how to `println` some text?

Comment: You can try `MultiLineLabel` if all you want is line breaks.

Comment: nice multiline works but I can you set as correct answer because you add this inc commpent

Comment: @biziclop  Please upgrade your comment to an answer.  (I doubt you got notified of the OP's latest comment.)

Comment: If your input is HTML formatted eg. with break tags, you can setEscapeModelStrings to false, so that your html formatting can be interpreted. This seems not to be what you are looking for, but it may help anyways

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use a `<pre />` (as in: *preformatted*) tag instead of `<span />`. If you have new line markers in your text, it will work, because browsers do not format text that is placed inside the `<pre />` tag.
2. Use Wicket's [`MultiLineLabel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html) class. After the [Javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html):

   > Unlike [`Label`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/Label.html), [`MultiLineLabel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html) shows text that spans multiple lines by inserting line breaks (`BR tags`) for newlines and paragraph markers (`P tags`) for sequences of more than one newline.

Note, that if using the [MultiLineLabel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html) class, you should not use a `<span />` tag in your HTML, as placing paragraphs (`<p />`) inside `<span />` is considered bad practice.

Comment: If you know how to contact [www.wicket-library.com](http://www.wicket-library.com) maintainers, you should ask them to fix the code sample. It could use `<div />` for example, or any other _block_ tag, but not `<span />` as it's inline and shouldn't contain other tags.

Comment: When using MultiLineLabel don't forget to set setEscapeModelStrings(false) on your label. Otherwise the br tags are not parsed but literally printed.

Comment: @Aster or just use newline character and let MultiLinelabel do its job ;-)